# How to compare 2 ema from an other timeframe

Tags: pine-script

I have some troubles to do a simple task :

- I have my chart on the 5mins timeframe.
- I'm using 2 EMA from the 30mins timeframe.

I want a simple condition : if ema1 > ema2 => condition true

But if I open a long or a short with this condition, it only checks the condition every 30mins (because my ema are from the 30mins timeframe).
I would like that every 5mins candles, I check the current 30mins ema value, and if the condition is true, then I can open a trade.

I hope it was understandable, thanks in advance !

EDIT : I add a screenshot, for better understanding :

I did a simple strategy : if emaYellow < emaPink then short.

I added some white rectangle, every 30mins. We can see the ema changing value, and it's only at this moment that my strategy open a short. Even if the emaYellow was < at my emaPink before (each candles between "Short End" and "Short Entry", it waits the new 30mins value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you would have to go on a 30m chart and use that function ([https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security_lower_tf](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity_lower_tf)) to retrieve the 5m data

Dave

Comment: Hi, I guess it could do the trick, but I would prefer to stay on the 5mins and retrieve 30mins chart data. My current "bad" solutions would be to do something like : condition = ema1 > ema2 or ema1[1] > ema2[1] or ema1[2] > ema2[2] etc... Until ema[5] and I would be sure to get the right 5mins candle that own the 30mins candle data. But it's not clean at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you chart is on the 5 min timeframe and you use request.security from 30 min timeframe this should be calculated each 5 minutes.

Have you tried this :

```
ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ta.ema(..) )
ema2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ta.e(..) )
if ema1 > ema2
    ...
```

It should work, shouldn't it!

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't. That's what I'm doing, but the condition ema1 > ema2 only triggers each 6 5mins-candles, which mean each new value on the 30mins timeframe.

Comment: If you try << ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ta.ema(close[1],15) )>> the value changes only every 30 minutes. It only triggers every 30 minutes, it's normal, isn't it

Comment: I added a screenshot to my initial question, I hope it's more understandable that way

Comment: I see. The strategy waits until the end of the current 30 min bar. In this case you should use the former 30 min bar as in : ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ta.ema(close[1],15) )

Answer (score 0):

Here I have calculated continous ema of higher timeframe on lower timeframe chart. Please use emlive1 and emplive2 (which are plotted at the end) for the calculations.

```
//@version=5
indicator("EMA HTF Live",overlay=true)
tf=input.timeframe("30","EMA TimeFrame")
period1=input.int(9)
period2=input.int(14)
[bi,cls,emperiod1,emperiod2]=request.security(syminfo.tickerid,tf,[bar_index,close,ta.ema(close,period1),ta.ema(close,period2)])
var clst=cls
if bi>bi[1]
    clst:=cls
else
    clst:=na
var emlive1=0.0
var emlive2=0.0
emlive1:=(emperiod1*(period1-1)+close*2)/(period1+1)
emlive2:=(emperiod2*(period2-1)+close*2)/(period2+1)
if bi>bi[1]
    emlive1:=emperiod1
    emlive2:=emperiod2
plot(emlive1,color=color.red)
plot(emlive2,color=color.green)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you instead of :

```
ema1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", ta.ema(close,15) )
```

I would use :

```
ema1 = ta.ema(close,90)
```

it does the trick